# Ordenar un arrayList usando un atributo String complejo con numeros y letras

Tags: java, arraylist, ordenamiento, comparaciones

Quiero ordenar un ArrayList de vehiculos según su matrícula. La matricula tiene un formato de 4 numeros seguidos por 3 letras mayúsculas. Por ejemplo:
String matricula = 1234QQQ
He implementado en mi clase Vehiculo el interfaz Comparable y estoy diseñando el metodo compareTo.He conseguido que me ordene en base a los numeros pero no consigo que me ordene en base a las letras. De manera que las matriculas 1111ZZZ y 1111AAA me coloca delante la que haya introducido primero. Sin embargo 2222RRR y 1111RRR si los ordena correctamente.
La imagen muestro:
-- Vehiculo implementa Comparable

-- El metodo compareTo. Creo que elproblema lo tengo en el else, ya que los números los ordena bien.

--El método listarVehiculos de la clase concesionario donde llamo al método sort y le paso por parametro el nombre del ArrayList (concesiona)

Muchas gracias por el feedback. Considero que tengo el problema en el else, cuando pretendo ordenar la parte "string" de la matricula. En la imagen que adjunto he recopilado lo referente al orden del ArrayList, y reitero que parte del método CompareTo está bien porque ordena la parte numérica de la matrícula. Supongo que te refieres a eso con pedir que compile y funcione. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando se busca ayuda con la depuración de código es muy importante aportar un [mre]. Si quiero intentar ver qué está pasando en tu código, tendría que inventarme la lógica de las clases y métodos que usas y las cuales no veo implementadas, con lo cual mi código podría no funcionar *igual* que el tuyo... Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade un ejemplo que ***compile y funcione*** para que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Por qué quitaste el código anterior?

Comment: Porque hoy le he dado más vueltas al código a ver si conseguía mejorarlo, pero al final sigo en las mismas. El codigo de ayer y de hoy es practicamente el mismo. Está en la imagen que he añadido.

Comment: ¿Por qué no comparas el String matricula completo, debería ordenarlos correctamente?

Comment: Muchas Gracias Lucas, cómo me estaba complicando la vida de manera tan tonta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que me ordena las matrículas usando el String completo:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Vehiculo_08 o) {
    
    int valorDevuelto;
        
        if (matricula.compareTo(o.getMatricula()) > 0) {
            valorDevuelto = 1;
        } else if (matricula.compareTo(o.getMatricula()) < 0) {
            valorDevuelto = -1;
        } else {
            valorDevuelto = 0;
        }
    return valorDevuelto;
}
```